# std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any> throws annoying compile errors

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, unordered-map, boost-any

When I declare a variable of `std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any>` type, it throws annoying compile errors.

For an example, **any.cc**:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main() {
    std::map<boost::any, boost::any> dict;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling above code as `g++ any.cc -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/boost` occurs a lot of errors like following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/unordered_map:47,
                 from any.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> >’:
/usr/include/c++/5/type_traits:137:12:   required from ‘struct std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > >’
/usr/include/c++/5/type_traits:148:38:   required from ‘struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:100:66:   required from ‘class std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any>’
any.cc:5:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/hashtable_policy.h:85:34: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<boost::any>) (const boost::any&)’
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/unordered_map:38,
                 from any.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:100:66:   required from ‘class std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any>’
any.cc:5:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/type_traits:148:38: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > >’
     : public integral_constant<bool, !_Pp::value>
                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/unordered_map:48:0,
                 from any.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h: In instantiation of ‘class std::unordered_map<boost::any, boost::any>’:
any.cc:5:48:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:100:66: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef __umap_hashtable<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>  _Hashtable;
                                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:107:45: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::key_type key_type;
                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:108:47: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::value_type value_type;
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:109:48: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::mapped_type mapped_type;
                                                ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:110:43: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::hasher hasher;
                                           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:111:46: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::key_equal key_equal;
                                              ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:112:51: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::allocator_type allocator_type;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:117:45: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::pointer  pointer;
                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:118:50: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_pointer const_pointer;
                                                  ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:119:47: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::reference  reference;
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:120:52: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_reference const_reference;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:121:46: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::iterator  iterator;
                                              ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:122:51: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_iterator const_iterator;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:123:51: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::local_iterator local_iterator;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:124:57: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::const_local_iterator const_local_iterator;
                                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:125:47: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::size_type  size_type;
                                               ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:126:52: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       typedef typename _Hashtable::difference_type difference_type;
                                                    ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:280:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:379:2: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
  emplace(_Args&&... __args)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:432:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:439:2: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
  insert(_Pair&& __x)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:499:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       insert(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:645:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       equal_range(const key_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unordered_map.h:649:7: error: ‘value’ is not a member of ‘std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_fast_hash<std::hash<boost::any> >, std::__detail::__is_noexcept_hash<boost::any, std::hash<boost::any> > > >’
       equal_range(const key_type& __x) const
       ^
```

But when I use `boost::unordered_map` rather than `std`, it works without any errors.

Why?

Comment: I know the message is huge, which makes tempting to give up right away, but usually the key with these errors is to look for types that you don't recognize and/or didn't ask for. If you just read a bit into this one, you'll see the reference to `std::hash`, which you didn't code and therefore indicates the `map` is trying to use it, as the answers explain.

Comment: @underscore_d Okay, I know I confused like your comment and didn't effort hard. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` uses `std::hash` as default hasher. There is no specialization of `std::hash` for `boost::any`. Because STanDard library does not know anything about entity from 3rd party library.

`boost::unordered_map` uses `boost::hash` as default hasher, which has specialization for types from boost library.

Solution: explicitely tell `std::unordered_map` to use `boost::hash<boost::any>` as hasher.

Comment: Thank you. It helps me understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare an `unordered_map<Key, Value>`, you need a hashing function. The default hashing function is const `hash<Key>(const Key&)`.

`boost::any`, it appears, has such hashing template specialization, but for `boost::hash`.

So in effect the compiler tries to find a specialization for `std::hash` for `boost::any`, but finds only `boost::hash` specialization.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness answer.